# Parse out the email body using perl

Tags: perl, email, extract

This is my perl code:

```
my $email = Email::Simple->new($brutEmail);
my $body = $email->body;

print $body;
```

And the result is

```
    --0016364d2ceb8da59d048be66a88 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1 Mail content email contents email contentss 
emails contentsss emmails contentsssss emmmail cccontent
    --0016364d2ceb8da59d048be66a88--
```

Or

```
    --0016364d2ceb8da59d048be66a88 Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable eMail 
content eMail content eMail content eMail content eMail content eMail content 
    --0016364d2ceb8da59d048be66a88--
```

I just want to retrieve the message body without the headers.

```
eMail content eMail content eMail content eMail content eMail content eMail content
```

Any Idea? without regexp..

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [`Email::MIME`](http://p3rl.org/Email::MIME) fits the bill. It's a more advanced version of `Email::Simple`.